# Full English translation of Eiji Yoshikawa's novel Musashi

Tags: translation, japanese-language, musashi, eiji-yoshikawa

Is there a full English translation of the novel *Musashi* (『宮本武蔵』) by Eiji Yoshikawa? The one usually available from Charles Terry is abridged.